# Conditional expectation in Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

Considering a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, let $N(t_2)$ denote the number of events in $(0,t_2]$ and $N(t_1, t_3)$ denote the number of events in $(t_1,t_3]$, under the assumption that $0<t_1<t_2<t_3$. I want to compute the conditional density $E(Y\mid X)$.

\begin{align}
E(Y\mid X) = E(Y\mid X=x) &= \sum_y yP_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) \\
&= \sum_y y P(Y=y\mid X=x)\\ 
&= \sum_y y \frac{P(Y=y,X=x)}{P(X=x)} \\
&= \sum_y y \frac{P(N(t_1, t_3)=y,N(t_2)=x)}{P(N(t_2)=x)} \\
\end{align}
At this point, it is immediate how the denominator is to be computed (since $N(t_2)$ is a discrete Poisson r.v.). The problematic point is the joint distribution in the numerator $P(N(t_1, t_3)=y,N(t_2)=x)$ since the intervals are overlapping and hence the corresponding r.v.s are not independent.

One way I thought of tackling this issue was by splitting the intervals into disjoint pieces,i.e. $(0, t_1]$, $(t_1, t_2]$ and $(t_2, t_3]$ and consider the corresponding random variables $N(t_1), N(t_1, t_2)$ and $N(t_2, t_3)$. Then I want to transform the joint distribution to:

\begin{align}P(N(t_1, t_3)=y,N(t_2)=x) &= P(N(t_1, t_2) + N(t_2, t_3)=y,N(t_1) + N(t_1, t_2)=x) \\
&= P(N(t_1, t_2)=y - N(t_2, t_3), N(t_1, t_2)=x-N(t_1)) \\
&= P(y - N(t_2, t_3) = x-N(t_1)) \\
&= P(N(t_1) + N(t_2, t_3) = x+y)
\end{align}

First of all, is there a mistake I am not spotting? And second, is this approach worth it (assuming it's correct)? Please feel free to suggest alternative approaches that might make this faster and more elegant/computationally less painful. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't read it carefully but what you wrote seems ok. I don't know much about poisson process but intuition tells me that, conditioning to $N(t_2)$, $N(t_1,t_3)$ is the sum of a binomial and a poisson (assuming independence). But let's wait for someone to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as the comment pointed out:

Note that $N(t_1, t_3) = N(t_1, t_2) + N(t_2, t_3)$. $N(t_2, t_3)$ is independent of $N(0, t_2)$ and has a Poisson distribution (independent increment):
$$ N(t_2, t_3) \sim \text{Poisson} (\lambda(t_3 - t_2))$$
Conditional on $N(0, t_2)$, $N(t_1, t_2)$ has a Binomial distribution (a well known result which can be easily proved):
$$ N(t_1, t_2)|N(0, t_2) = x \sim \text{Binomial}\left(x, \frac {t_2 - t_1} {t_2}\right) $$
Therefore,

$$ \begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[N(t_1, t_3)|N(0, t_2) = x] 
& = \mathbb{E}[N(t_1, t_2) + N(t_2, t_3)|N(0, t_2) = x] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[N(t_1, t_2)|N(0, t_2) = x] + \mathbb{E}[N(t_2, t_3)] \\
& = x \frac {t_2 - t_1} {t_2} + \lambda(t_3 - t_2)
\end{align*} $$
Since this holds for every $x$ in the support of $X$, you can replace the $x$ by the random variable $X$ for calculating $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the very detailed answer!