# How does one do conditional expected value with a Poisson process?

Tags: probability

I am working on a problem and reduced it to this part, but am now confused. I have never done conditional expected value with a Poisson process.

Let $Z$ and $X$ be Poisson processes with homogenous rate $\lambda$. Suppose further that $Z = N(t_1,t_2]$ while $X = N[0,t_2]$ and where $0<t_1 < t_2$

I need to find 
$$\Bbb E [Z | X = x] $$

I don't know how to compute this.

---

**my thoughts**

$$\Bbb E [Z | X = x] = \sum_{z = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z \Bbb P(Z = z \cap X=x)}{\Bbb P(X=x)}$$

But since $Z$ and $X$ overlap, what do I do? I know 
$$\Bbb P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t_2}(\lambda t_2) ^x}{x!}$$

But how do I calculate $\Bbb P(Z = z \cap X=x)$?

---

am I on the right track for being able to find $\Bbb E [Z | X = x] $?

I believe the answer is $x\left(\frac{t_2-t_1}{t_2}\right)$

Comment: To say that "$Z$ is a Poisson process" and then "$Z=(t1,t2]$" looks as nonsense to me. ($Z$ cannot be at the same time a discrete value, a continuous processes and an interval...) You seem to be confusing the concept of a Poisson random variable (which takes non-negative integer values) with a Poisson process. Perhaps you mean that $Z$ is a Poisson variable that counts the "points/events" of a homogeneous Poisson process in the interval $I_Z=(t1,t2]$ ?  If so, you need to also make clear if $X$ and $Z$ counts the events of the same process (I guess so) or of independent processes.

Comment: I think the corrections you suggested are what I am asking. I tried to edit it, I hope this helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same set up of the question that I answered yesterday:

[Conditional expectation in Poisson point process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618861/conditional-expectation-in-poisson-point-process/)

which I intentionally left this part as I think it is a rather well known result in Poisson process and can be easily proved. So it should be a good time to fill this part as OP ask for clarification. The key trick of this question is to use the independent increment of Poisson process. We calculate the conditional pmf of $N(t_1, t_2)$, given $N(0, t_2) = x$:

$$\begin{align*} \Pr\{N(t_1, t_2) = z|N(0, t_2) = x\} 
&= \frac {\Pr\{N(t_1, t_2) = z, N(0, t_2) = x\} } {\Pr\{N(0, t_2) = x\}} \\
&= \frac {\Pr\{N(t_1, t_2) = z, N(0, t_1) = x - z\} } {\Pr\{N(0, t_2) = x\}} \\
&= \frac {\Pr\{N(t_1, t_2) = z\}\Pr\{N(0, t_1) = x - z\} } 
{\Pr\{N(0, t_2) = x\}} \\
& = \frac {\displaystyle e^{-\lambda(t_2-t_1)} \frac {[\lambda(t_2 - t_1)]^z} {z!} e^{-\lambda t_1} \frac {(\lambda t_1)^{x-z}} {(x-z)!}} 
{\displaystyle e^{-\lambda t_2} \frac {(\lambda t_2)^x} {x!}} \\
& = \frac {x!} {z!(x-z)!} \left(\frac {t_2 - t_1} {t_2}\right)^z \left(1 - \frac {t_2 - t_1} {t_2}\right)^{x-z}, z = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, x
\end{align*}$$
So it shows that $\displaystyle N(t_1, t_2)|N(0, t_2) = x \sim \text{Binomial}\left(x, \frac {t_2 - t_1} {t_2}\right)$

After you have found out the conditional distribution to be binomial, the expectation just follows from the standard result.